# Forces acting when sliding

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces

I have problem: An object of mass $m$ slides down on an inclined plane with a constant velocity $v$. The friction constant is equal to $f$. What is
the power loss due to the force causing the object to slide down?

So I tried to figure it out and I came up with something like this 
$$
(\frac{mv^2}{2}+0)-(0+mgs)=-mgf\cos \alpha s
$$

Can someone confirm that?

Comment: Do you mean "the constant friction is equal to f"? By the way, would you mind showing the work up until this result?

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  Forces don't have power, and forces don't slide down objects.

Comment: Note : If the speed $\:v\:$ is constant then $\:f=\tan \alpha\:$ where $\:\alpha\:$ the inclination angle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible that you are complicating things. If it is moving with constant velocity, it is not accelerated. This means the friction force does compensate the acceleration due to gravity. Most importantly it means that all potential energy is lost via friction, as it is not used for a gain in kinetic energy. So if its speed is $v$, the energy is $E=m g h$, you only need to calculate how much height difference it is doing per time $t$ (as a function of $v$). Having Power $P=E/t$, you'll get it, right?